# Function with two completing-read

Tags: completion

I want a function designed to accept two `completing-read` calls, one to set `nstruc` that holds either `"Glyph"` or `"Command"`, and `actm` that holds either `"alpha α"` or `"beta β"`.

The two variables are then intended to be used inside the body of the function, within the `pcase` construct shown.

```
(defun greek (actm)
  "TODO"

  (interactive
   (list
    (let ( nstruc 
           (csel '("Glyph" "Command") )   
           (cseq '("alpha α" "beta β")) )
      (setq nstruc (completing-read "Instruc: " csel nil t nil))
      (completing-read "Letter: " cseq nil t nil) )))

  (pcase actm
    ("alpha α" (insert "\\alpha"))
    ("beta β"  (insert "\\beta")) )
```

Perhaps I do not need to put the `completing-read` calls in the interactive clause, but in the body of the function.

```
(defun my-custom-function ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((first-choice (completing-read "Enter your first choice: "))
        (second-choice (completing-read "Enter your second choice: ")))
    (message "First choice: %s, Second choice: %s" first-choice second-choice)))
```

When you use this function, Emacs will prompt you to enter two choices, and it will display the entered choices in the message area.

Comment: Is your question how to design a function that fits your description? Or is your question something specific about the code you show? The latter would bit this Q&A site, but the specific question is missing. The former would be too abstract. Either way, missing detail.

Comment: Why is it important to enter either `\alpha` or `α` ? What problem will this code solve for you? There may be packages out there that already solve your problem.  For instance, see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688137/1299

Comment: @Trevoke Because that is what I want the function to do.  Do you have an elisp solution to my function that works, or do you not ?

Comment: I *guess* OP wants to ask what is the difference between `(interactive ... completing-read ...)` and `(interactive) ... (completing-read ...)`.

Comment: @Mahavir "because that is what I want the function to do" is a non-answer. We're here to solve people's problems, not to do people's homework. Real-world problems have context, homework problems do not.

Comment: I cleared up obsolete comments and edited the question to remove a tack-on question that was added after the fact. For "how the interactive bit of code in elisp works", the best source of information is the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is on how to make the variable nstruc available for use in the pcase part.

You can't. `nstruc` only exists within the scope of your `interactive` form.

If your function needs a value from `interactive` it should be a part of the *list of function arguments* being returned by `interactive`, so that you can get it from there.

Change your function to accept *two* arguments and you could make this trivial adjustment:

```el
(interactive
 (let (nstruc
       (csel '("Glyph" "Command"))
       (cseq '("alpha α" "beta β")))
   (list
    (setq nstruc (completing-read "Instruc: " csel nil t nil))
    (completing-read "Letter: " cseq nil t nil))))
```

Or without the `nstruc` redundancy:

```el
(interactive
 (let ((csel '("Glyph" "Command"))
       (cseq '("alpha α" "beta β")))
   (list
    (completing-read "Instruc: " csel nil t nil)
    (completing-read "Letter: " cseq nil t nil))))
```